# Show only new available and new updated apps in Google Play Store

Tags: google-play-store

Is there a way to show only new apps and games or new updated games and apps in the Play Store? I don't mean the top new games section because apps in there are mostly old (few days/weeks). A few month ago there was such a section but it was removed. I'd like to get this section back, maybe on another website or with an API if necessary.